# Reuse keys of first argument in another argument with generics

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to google how to solve this problem but I'm having a hard time even coming up with *what* to search for, so any help in editing this question or linking me to duplicates would be very helpful.

### The Use Case

I have a function that as a first argument takes a Record of "column names" as the keys and interface fields as the values. For example, a mapping of,

```json
{
  "user_id": "userID",
  "email__": "email",
}
```

and an interface of,

```js
interface ExpectedShape {
  userID: number;
  email: string;
}
```

### Casting

For reasons beyond my control, the columns where my data is coming above are named `user_id` and `email__`, and will always be returned as strings. So I need to define how to cast or clean up incoming data when creating JS objects matching the `ExpectedShape` interface.

So in order to allow this, I have a configuration variable in my method that will take **the same keys** as the original mapping but have methods that will cast things accordingly. For example,

```js
{
  "user_id": Number.parseInt,
  "email__": sanitizeEmail,
}
```

So when `user_id` comes in from the data source, it will call `Number.parseInt` so that when it the `ExpectedShape` object is built, it'll be a proper number.

### What I want to do

Via TypeScript, I want to enforce that the keys of my "mapping" and my "casting operations" be the same.

Here is some **broken** code that does not work but shows what I'd envision it to look like.

```js
interface ExpectedShape {
    userID: number;
    email: string;
}

interface FunctionOptions<K extends keyof any, S> {
    casting: Record<K, (value: string) => S[keyof S]>;
}

function myFunction<T extends {}>(
    values: Record<string, keyof T>,
    config: FunctionOptions<keyof values, T>, // <-- What can I put here?
): Partial<T> {
    return {};
}

function sanitizeEmail(_: string): string { return ""; }

const result = myFunction<ExpectedShape>(
    {
      "user_id": "userID",
      "email__": "email",
    },
    {
        // I want to restrict via TypeScript that the keys of `casting` must be
        // the same as the keys of the `values` argument. See how it's missing
        // an underscore?
        casting: {
            userid: Number.parseInt,
        }
    },
);
```

### What I have tried...

I have tried a lot. The closest I've gotten it to work and compile successfully is this,

```js
function myFunction<
    T extends {},
    M extends Record<string, keyof T> = Record<string, keyof T>,
    P extends keyof M = keyof M,
>(
    values: M,
    config: FunctionOptions<P, T>,
): Partial<T> {
    return {};
}
```

However. It does not enforce keys correctly and allows me to use whatever keys I want.

Comment: Your "broken" code seems to have typos or something that prevent me from fully understanding the exact nature of what you're doing (is `values` supposed to be a mapping of keys to keys?  If so, why are you passing in `Number.parseInt` and `sanitizeEmail`?  How could `myFunction` return a `Partial<T>` when you don't even pass in a value from the original API?).  My answer will just involve a general way of doing this at runtime and in the type system, and hopefully you can adapt it to whatever your specific use case is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in order for this to work either at runtime or at the type system, you need to pass in something like three arguments: the input object you'd like to process; an object that maps the keys of the input object to those of the output object; and an object that maps the values of the input object to those of the output object.  Presumably the key mapper would just be an object whose values are just keys, while the value mapper would be an object whose values are functions.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
function mapKeysAndValues<I extends object,
  KM extends Record<keyof I, S>,
  VM extends { [K in keyof I]: (v: I[K]) => any },
  S extends PropertyKey
>(
  inputObject: I,
  keyMapping: KM,
  valMapping: VM
): { [K in keyof I as KM[K]]: ReturnType<VM[K]> } {

  const ret: any = {};
  (Object.keys(inputObject) as Array<keyof I>).forEach(k =>
    ret[keyMapping[k]] = valMapping[k](inputObject[k] as any)
  )
  return ret;
}
```

We have three important generic type parameters here: `I` corresponds to the input object, `KM` corresponds to the key mapping object, and `VM` corresponds to the value mapping object.

( The type parameter `S` doesn't do much except provide a hint that we'd like the values of the key mapping object to be interpreted by the compiler as [literal values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) and not something useless like `string`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a feature request discussing this.  You can mostly ignore `S` ).

The heavy lifting is in the return type of `mapKeysAndValues()`.  We use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to replace each key `K` in the input with `KM[K]` in the output.  And we use [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) in the property value to grab the return type of each property `K`'s function in `VM` and use it as the value type for the corresponding property of the output type.

The implementation uses a bunch of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to prevent the compiler from complaining (it really won't understand key remapping or correlated functions), but at runtime you can see it mostly just walks through the input object keys and performs the transformation for each one.  (It is technically possible that `inputObject` might have extra properties not known of the the compiler, so you might want to make this more safe by doing additional runtime checks like `if (k in valMapping)` and `if (typeof valMapping[k] === "function")`.  But I'll ignore that possibility.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const ret: ExpectedShape = mapKeysAndValues(
  { "user_id": "123", "email__": "foo@example.com" },
  { "user_id": "userID", "email__": "email" },
  { "user_id": Number.parseInt, "email__": sanitizeEmail }
)

console.log(ret);
/* {
  "userID": 123,
  "email": "foo@example.com"
}  */
```

Looks good! The compiler understands that `mapKeysAndValues()` will produce a value of the `ExpectedShape` type, and when we log it to the console we see that the right thing happened at runtime too.

Hopefully you can use `mapKeysAndValues()` as a starting point for the transformation that you're trying to accomplish.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RLJNIZLIAmjkZAAIgY0FswDwFY4FYAjAAmADMFeGFdE4gktlsDcrhu0AAEZnBuJgJBAJZzuBXbsJy1XGFBa-XG9WoKxO5We5J+4Pu1YJAulHdl1v14OAHI8fhQCWYOBQRhMcBd-d9gfSQzGMwWCeQQ4vGXLaNOEoSNo8jWDaThCAA9AAVGyNArswLCDq2bZ3MevZHsOY7oBOU4znOFaUKyyBIQhqhAA)

Comment: looks like I made some typos in my question's sample code, which I've fixed. But your assumptions in what I meant and answering my question were spot on! Thank you! This sorcery was able to get me to what I wanted